# How can I change orientation and position of the modebar PlotlyJS

Tags: javascript, plotly

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXaqE.png)

how can i change orientation to vertical and change position of the modebar to the right of the chart like the image ? What should i edit in layout and config ?

```
 let layout = {
    xaxis: {
        title: 'Date',
        tickfont: {
            size: 10,
        },
    },
    yaxis: {
        title: '価格 ($)',
        tickfont: {
            size: 10,
        },
        range: [minValue, maxValue],
    },
    legend: {
        x: -0.05,
        y: 1.2,
        itemwidth: 30,
        traceorder: 'normal',
        orientation: 'h',
        font: {
            size: 12,
            color: '#000',
        },
    },
};

let config = {
    responsive: true,
    scrollZoom: true,
    displaylogo: false,
};

Plotly.newPlot('model_graph', all_traces, layout, config);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the orientation, see [`layout.modebar.orientation`](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/layout/#layout-modebar-orientation) :

```js
const layout = {
  // ...

  modebar: {
    orientation: 'v'
  }
};
```

For the position, you can override the modebar container styles, which has `position: absolute; top: 0px;` by default (nb. defaults are applied inline). Basically, you need to increase the `top` according to the [layout top margin](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/layout/#layout-margin-t) (default: 100px) :

```css
.modebar-container {
  top: 100px !important;
}
```

[Try it on codepen](https://codepen.io/lvlte/pen/rNogVxr)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: it didn't help so much, the modebar will seperate into 3 column next by next. Btw I solved it by edit css file

Comment: @Mikel If you don't get something like the above screenshot, assuming you managed to copy/paste the relevant code correctly, it's likely that your existing config and css is messing with plotly styles. What doesn't help is saying "_Btw I solved it by edit css file_" without providing (what you think is) the solution. I added a live example on codepen, try to add your code progressively and check when/where it breaks.